# App Crashing GameCenterUI: specialized AccessPointRootViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations.getter

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, crash-reports, gamekit

I'm receiving a crash in my iOS game. This game utilizes GKAccessPoints and the Game Center UI's. I only noticed this crash in the released versions of my game (non-beta versions).

The reason I think this has something to do with GameKit is because of where it says GameCenterUI and access point. Other than that I'm not sure what's causing this. I have tried opening the crash it in my project and it did not pinpoint a line of code that was causing this. This makes me think that this could be an error with Apple's GameKit class. But then again I'm not sure. I am attaching a full crash report (I am erasing some sensitive information like app). I removed the Binary Image section because of character limits.

Any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated. If you need more information just ask. thank you.

```
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           



OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.4.2 (18D70)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    3.02.02
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001a39dba18
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [1890]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001a39dba18 _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 492 (AssertCommon.swift:132)
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001a39dba18 _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 492 (AssertCommon.swift:132)
2   GameCenterUI                    0x00000001b7090f60 specialized AccessPointRootViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations.getter + 276 (GKAccessPoint.swift:33)
3   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a205e10c -[UIViewController __supportedInterfaceOrientations] + 708 (UIViewController.m:9782)
4   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a204e418 -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenCurrentOrientation:] + 120 (UIViewController.m:6492)
5   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a27b1470 -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 328 (UIWindow.m:3893)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019fd0e9a0 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 28 (CFNotificationCenter.c:706)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019fd0e948 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 52 (CFNotificationCenter.c:173)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019fd0deb0 _CFXRegistrationPost + 440 (CFNotificationCenter.c:198)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019fd0d870 _CFXNotificationPost + 716 (CFNotificationCenter.c:1071)
10  Foundation                      0x00000001a0fd44bc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64 (NSNotification.m:575)
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2761c54 -[UIApplication _stopDeactivatingForReason:] + 964 (UIApplication.m:1899)
12  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1dc12a0 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 440 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:108)
13  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1dc161c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 768 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:548)
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1dc0e58 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 340 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:454)
15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a1bec1a0 -[UIScene _invalidate] + 804 (UIScene.m:683)
16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a29e5014 -[UIWindowScene _invalidate] + 52 (UIWindowScene.m:268)
17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2769180 -[UIApplication workspace:willDestroyScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 208 (UIApplication.m:3725)
18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a226505c -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:willInvalidateWithEvent:completion:] + 388 (UIApplicationSceneClientAgent.m:61)
19  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001afb1a570 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_willDestroyWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 276 (FBSScene.m:452)
20  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001afb47b1c __84-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _queue_invalidateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 128 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:574)
21  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001afb294a0 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 240 (FBSWorkspace.m:355)
22  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001afb4796c __84-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _queue_invalidateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 328 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:573)
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f9a5db0 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019f9a9738 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 268 (queue.c:468)
25  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001afb6e250 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 48 (FBSSerialQueue.m:184)
26  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001afb6dee0 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 448 (FBSSerialQueue.m:227)
27  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001afb6e434 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 32 (FBSSerialQueue.m:258)
28  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019fd2d76c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1967)
29  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019fd2d668 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208 (CFRunLoop.c:2011)
30  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019fd2c960 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268 (CFRunLoop.c:2048)
31  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019fd26a8c __CFRunLoopRun + 824 (CFRunLoop.c:2925)
32  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019fd2621c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
33  GraphicsServices                0x00000001b78f0784 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2259)
34  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2766ee8 -[UIApplication _run] + 1072 (UIApplication.m:3253)
35  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a276c75c UIApplicationMain + 168 (UIApplication.m:4707)
36  libswiftUIKit.dylib             0x00000001b408b2e4 UIApplicationMain(_:_:_:_:) + 104 (UIKit.swift:528)
37  Tank Fighters                   0x0000000102c2e738 main + 80 (<compiler-generated>:12)
38  Tank Fighters                   0x0000000102c2e738 $main + 92 (StoreViewController.swift:0)
39  Tank Fighters                   0x0000000102c2e738 main + 108
40  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019f9e66b0 start + 4

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cdcdd2d0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cdcdc660 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019fd2cc30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 380 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019fd26c14 __CFRunLoopRun + 1216 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019fd2621c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a0fd5df0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232 (NSRunLoop.m:374)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a0fd5cbc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92 (NSRunLoop.m:421)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a281ac48 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 516 (UIEventFetcher.m:838)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001a1147a34 __NSThread__start__ + 864 (NSThread.m:724)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001eb85bcb0 _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:881)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001eb864778 thread_start + 8

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cdcdd2d0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cdcdc660 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019fd2cc30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 380 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019fd26c14 __CFRunLoopRun + 1216 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019fd2621c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   AudioSession                    0x00000001a786f0c4 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164 (GenericRunLoopThread.h:91)
6   AudioSession                    0x00000001a787125c CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 92 (CAPThread.cpp:321)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001eb85bcb0 _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:881)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001eb864778 thread_start + 8

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cdcdd2d0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cdcdc660 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019fd2cc30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 380 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019fd26c14 __CFRunLoopRun + 1216 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019fd2621c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   AudioToolbox                    0x00000001a8eca9fc GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164 (GenericRunLoopThread.h:91)
6   libAudioToolboxUtility.dylib    0x00000001b555b144 CADeprecated::CAPThread::Entry(CADeprecated::CAPThread*) + 92 (CAPThread.cpp:324)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001eb85bcb0 _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:881)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001eb864778 thread_start + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001eb864764 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001eb864764 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001eb864764 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001eb864764 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001eb864764 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x80000001b727eec0   x1: 0x00000002818cca80   x2: 0x0000000000000007   x3: 0x00000001afbaacdc
    x4: 0x00000000000062dc   x5: 0x000000016d1d9040   x6: 0x0000000000000077   x7: 0x0000000000000001
    x8: 0x000000000000007f   x9: 0x0000000000000016  x10: 0x00000000000007fb  x11: 0x00000000000007fd
   x12: 0x0000000000000001  x13: 0x00000000b8036818  x14: 0x00000000b8237000  x15: 0x000000000000006e
   x16: 0x0000000080000000  x17: 0x0000000038200000  x18: 0x00000001057f75b2  x19: 0x00000001b727f010
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x0000000000000021  x23: 0x00000001b727eeb0
   x24: 0x80000001b727eec0  x25: 0xd000000000000017  x26: 0x000000000000000b  x27: 0x0000000000000002
   x28: 0x0000000000000018   fp: 0x000000016d1d91e0   lr: 0x00000001a39dba18
    sp: 0x000000016d1d9160   pc: 0x00000001a39dba18 cpsr: 0x60000000
   esr: 0xf2000001  Address size fault


EOF
```